# GlassFish StandAlone no carga imagenes, elementos del JSF en los elementos primefaces y CSS

Tags: jsf, glassfish

Tengo un proyecto en netbeans que funciona perfectamente. Pero, cargo .war en mi glassfish standalone 4.1 (Esta versión es la misma que la versión netbeans)

Hago el .war por defecto de netbeans (limpiar y construir)

En el proyecto desplegado en GFish StandAlone no muestra ni fotos ni los elementos dentro de los componentes de las principales. Además, el tema de primefaces no carga el CSS

Muestra del uso de imagenes y css en los .xhtml

```
<h:head>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="resources" name="css/login.css"/>
    <style type="text/css">
        body{

                background-image: url("resources/images/fondoBlanco.jpg");
                background-size: cover;
                background-repeat: no-repeat; 
                background-attachment:fixed;
        }
    </style>
</h:head>
```

Muestra de imagenes de botones

```
    <p:commandLink action="#{loginBean.sessGmail()}" ajax="true" type="submit" >
        <h:graphicImage library="resources" name="images/iconGmailBlack.png" style="width: 150px; height: 150px; "/>
        <f:param name="idParamtro" value="#{loginBean.userLog}" />
    </p:commandLink>
```

Toda la ayuda es apreciada

Comment: Pablo es bueno que nos muestre código para saber cómo podemos ayudar.

Comment: No sabría que código mostrar ya que parece un error de configuración o de declaración al desplegar la aplicación en standalone.  El error podría venir de no declarar elementos en web.xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si funciona en el GF/Netbeans, va a funcionar con el "standalone" GF a no ser que tenga configurado un `datasource,connectionpool, Realm`, de ser el caso, hay que configurar eso de forma manual ya que hay veces que el `glassfish-resources.xml` no se toma en cuenta... (un poco absurdo pero pasa). Pero de ser éste el caso debería salirle algúnn tipo de `StackTrace`. Puede revisar el `server log` para ver qué es lo que está pasando ya que no esta utilizando Netbeans, por lo que no tiene forma de ver la "consola". puede encontrar el server log en:

```
[lugar_de_instalación]\glassfish\domains\domain1\logs
```

en mi caso:

```
C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.1.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\logs
```

Muy probablemente éste archivo le aclare el por qué no le está funcionando como debe pero no creo que tenga mucho que ver con el descriptor de despliegue `web.xml` ya que éste lo configura netbeans al crear un projecto web.

Si lo modificó, asegúrese de tener como mínimo la siguiente configuración, de lo contrario las páginas no van a poder ser interpretadas por el browser:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" 
         xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">    


     // Activar el Servlet que se encarga de 
     // crear HTML a partir de etiquetas JSF
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>        
    </servlet>

    // Vincular el "Faces Servlet" 
    // con recursos que estén acorde al "url-pattern"
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    // Establecer qué página mostrar al iniciar la app.
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>welcome.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

**EDICIÓN**

JSF nos ayuda a cargar recursos externos de forma dinámica a través del [resource handler](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/ResourceHandler.html).

Este funciona de la siguiente forma:

1. hay que crear un folder llamado **resources** dentro de WebContent o
   Web Pages, éste tendrá los recursos que se van a utilizar en la app.
2. Para llamar un recurso, hay que seguir lo siguiente:

*Con ésta estructura:*

```
-Web Pages
    |___ WEB-INF
    |___ resources
            |__ css
            |    |_ estilosIndex.css
            |__ js
            |    |_ index.js
            |__ imagenes
                 |_ avatar.png
```

Si queremos llamar un recurso `CSS|Javascript` utilizamos:

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="estilosIndex.css" />
```

ó

```
<h:outputStylesheet name="css/estilosIndex.css" />
```

**No hay necesidad de llamar explícitamente al folder `resources`**

Lo mismo pasa con javascript:

```
<h:outputScript library="js" name="index.js" />
```

ó

Bien, ahora qué sucede con `Primefaces` ó componentes JSF `<h:...`.

Para llamar un recurso de imagen ubicada en `resources/` hay que utilizar el atributo `name`

```
<h:graphicImage name="imagenes/avatar.png" />

<p:graphicImage name="imagenes/avatar.png" />
```

ó

```
<h:graphicImage name="avatar.png" library="imagenes"/>

<p:graphicImage name="/avatar.png" library="imagenes"/>
```

El atributo `value` es para información binaria.

Para llamar recursos desde un archivo `css|js` hay que utilizar el resource bundle:

```
body{
  background: url("#{resource['imagenes/avatar.png']}");
}
```

Comment: Voy aprobar lo que me comentas y te contesto. Muchas gracias Esteban

Comment: He estado trabajando tu respuesta. He solucionado algunos de los problemas viendo el server.log, la solución a estos ha sido poner los ficheros de resources de netbeans en la carpeta de domains1/resources. Pero todavía no he solucionado el problema de las imagenes y el css (también las he puesto en domains1/resources ).

Comment: Muéstrame cómo estás haciendo para mostrar una imagen y para utilizar CSS por fa

Comment: Me salen varios warning relacionados con estos: WARNING jsf.application.resource.unable_to_serve_from_library   javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application 
  JSF1064: no se encuentra o sirve el recurso, images/addPlus.png, desde la biblioteca, resources  
WARNING jsf.context.extcontext.sessionmap.nonserializable javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application tid: _ThreadID=31 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)
  JSF1063: ADVERTENCIA Definiendo valor de atributo no serializable en HttpSession: (clave: mainBean, clase de valor: com.ws.MainBean)

Comment: He actualizado el post con un ejemplo llamada al css y a imagenes en el .xhtml

Comment: Ok, ya agrego respuesta

Comment: Lo que me comentas es como estoy realizando las llamadas y funciona en NetBeans/GF pero no en el GF-SAlone. Hay algunas llamadas que las tengo  como comentas y otras no. Pero todas funcionan bien en NB/GF

Comment: Según los WARNING que te salen. (1) No se encuentra el recurso `images/addPlus.png`

Comment: Asegúrarse de que MainBean sea `Serializable`

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias por la ayuda lo probaré y te comento

Comment: Mil gracias, se debía a que estaba poniendo el parametro (library="resources") no entiendo en verdad por que en GF/NB funciona con este parámetro y en GF StandAlone no funcionaba. Pero se debe al añadir este parámetro. Un saludo y muchas gracias de nuevo